# How to stop execution after inherited call?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, onmousedown, inherited

I use `TAdvGlowButton` button control from TMS and by default it sets `Down` property to true on `MouseDown`. I would like to be able to prevent setting this property to True, when needed. 
The execution flow on MouseDown starts in the MouseDown procedure of class:

```
procedure TAdvCustomGlowButton.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
...
begin
  inherited; // Calls my local OnMouseDown method
  ...        // <- I would like to skip/cancel/stop execution after inherited call, so it never gets to Down := True line
  Down = True; 
  ...

end;
```

I have my local on button OnMouseDown:

```
procedure TForm1.AdvGlowButton1MouseDown(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  ShowMessage('Local Mouse Down');
  if True then
    AdvGlowButton1.OnMouseDown:=nil; //<- I would like to stop execution 
end;
```

I tried to set OnMouseDown to nil, but that doesn't do work, execution flow gets back to MouseDown and keep going.

I would like to avoid, if possible, changing anything in original class.

**Is there a way to stop/abort/cancel further execution after original inherited call?**

Comment: You can raise an exception.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz  If I do 'raise Exception.Create('Stop flow...');' the the exception is handled in original MouseDown procedure - where I have no control on how to handle this exception. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Throwing an exception is the only way to do what you are asking (try raising `EAbort` via `SysUtils.Abort()`, the lower level VCL handlers will ignore it by default) without modifying `TAdvCustomGlowButton` itself, or deriving a custom class that overrides the `MouseDown()` method with your own logic and never calls the `inherited` method.

Comment: If I derive my own custom class and override MouseDown method, can I still call the original as it contains code that most of the time should be executed, bnut not all the time?

Comment: This doesn't feel like the right solution. What is the underlying problem.

Comment: Group of `TAdvGlowButtons` buttons can behave like radio buttons and `Down` property sets which one is `checked`. I would like to be able to control when not to allow a specific button to be checked. And `Down` property is protected and can't be set manually, so I was thinking of just to skip the part where class's `MouseDown` sets this property. I can do this by introducing a global Flag (`Exit_Method_After_Inhetired:boolean`) and set it to `true`, when I want. But would be best if I don't need to modify TMS's code in `AdvGlowButton` unit.

Comment: Better to code the entire grouping yourself.

Comment: I've decide to create new global flag to switch on/off execution after inherited with `If Exit_After_Inhetired Then Begin Exit_After_Imherited := False; Exit; End;`. Should I delete this question?

Comment: That sounds like a really bad way to implement this.

Comment: I know, eventually I will do my own grouping and ask questions on SO, if I need help. For now, this is quick workaround.